# Save and Read Key-Value pair in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, object-files, sequencefile

I have a JavaPairRDD in the following format:

```
JavaPairRDD< String, Tuple2< String, List< String>>> myData;
```

I want to save it as a Key-Value format `(String, Tuple2< String, List< String>>)`.

```
myData.saveAsXXXFile("output-path");
```

So my next job could read in the data directly to my `JavaPairRDD`:

```
JavaPairRDD< String, Tuple2< String, List< String>>> newData = context.XXXFile("output-path");
```

I am using Java 7, Spark 1.2, Java API. I tried `saveAsTextFile` and `saveAsObjectFile`, neither works. And I don't see `saveAsSequenceFile` option in my eclipse.

Does anyone have any suggestion for this problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SequenceFileRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.SequenceFileRDDFunctions) that is used through implicits in scala, however that might be nastier than using the usual suggestion for java of:

```
myData.saveAsHadoopFile(fileName, Text.class, CustomWritable.class,
                        SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

implementing `CustomWritable` via extending

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable
```

Something like this should work (did not check for compilation):

```
public class MyWritable extends Writable{
  private String _1;
  private String[] _2;

  public MyWritable(Tuple2<String, String[]> data){
    _1 = data._1;
    _2 = data._2;
  }

  public Tuple2<String, String[]> get(){
    return new Tuple2(_1, _2);
  }

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    _1 = WritableUtils.readString(in);
    ArrayWritable _2Writable = new ArrayWritable();
    _2Writable.readFields(in);
    _2 = _2Writable.toStrings();
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    Text.writeString(out, _1);
    ArrayWritable _2Writable = new ArrayWritable(_2);
    _2Writable.write(out);
  }
}
```

such that it fits your data model.

Comment: In this case, my CustomWritable is  Tuple2< String, List< String>> . I don't think I could make Tuple2< String, List< String>> Writable? Can I?

Comment: You could use implicits in scala to make it look like it is inherently possible. However, given Java, it will be best to just create a MyTuple2Writable and just map to it.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Could you point me to any document or example that could make  Tuple2< String, List< String>> Writable ? Thanks!